# Query implementation in MongoDB with pretty()

Tags: database, mongodb

I need to display information about the isbn and title of all books with a topic "Computer Science" from a file "bookshop.js". The issue I am having is with the results after processing the query. The results are not in a .pretty() format even though I am using that method in my query:

```
db.bookshop.find({"BOOK.topic":"Computer Science", "BOOK.price":{$gt:70}},{"BOOK.isbn":1, "BOOK.title":1, _id:0}).pretty()
```

Here is the expected output:

```
{
     "BOOK" : {
         "isbn" : "12345678",
         "title" : "Database Systems"
     }
}
{
     "BOOK" : {
         "isbn" : "65837856",
         "title" : "Algorithms"
     }
}
{
     "BOOK" : {
         "isbn" : "94617290",
         "title" : "Networks"
     }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
{ "BOOK" : { "isbn" : "12345678","title" : "Database Systems"}}
{ "BOOK" : { "isbn" : "65837856","title" : "Algorithms"}}
{ "BOOK" : { "isbn" : "94617290","title" : "Networks"}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am quite new to MongoDB.

Comment: Which tool do you use? It may reformat the output. Maybe try `JSON.stringify(..., null, " ")`

Comment: I think `.pretty()` is really just used to output the response in a human-readable format. If you want to add indentation and breakpoints you may need to do that after you get the query.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit is right. One addition you could also add to his example is the following: `JSON.stringify(yourMongoData, null, 4);`